# FTP Database to webhost server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, web-hosting

I have written an asp.net mvc application that is connected to a Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio database and I want to deploy the application to the webhosting server now. I have managed to get the published code onto the server easily. However, I want to ftp the database I created in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to the server. Where are these created databases saved and is it possible to ftp the database to the server. The other issue is the web hosting server is using MS SQL Server Express is that a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally shared hosts expect you to place the database in the App_Data folder and use it directly from there.

Here is a page to explain connecting to the database

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257.aspx

To find the database on your system open sql management studio right click the Database and click Properties on the Properties windows click on the Files section to show all associated files with your database.

I would recommend checking your providers documentaion though they might have specific requirments for database deployments